# MAUI Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth Nuget package errors

Tags: nuget, google-play-services, maui

I can make a new MAUI project with .Net 6.0 and add the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth v120.5.0 Nuget package and I receive this error.

[image]

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new project and I can reproduce the problem. And then, I tested some other version of the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth` nuget package.

I found that this problem just appear on the version **v120.5.0**. So you can try to use the version **v120.4.0.1** or lower. I tested with these version in my project and it can build successfully.

And you can also post an new issue for [this package on the github](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues).